# Change the startup menu icon (I've tried multiple ways in Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS) and have not been successful

Tags: 20.04, gnome, icons, launcher, themes

Recently, I wanted to change the Ubuntu startup menu (Applications menu see below for the 9 dot square icon) to a different icon. See where the mouse is hovering in this picture for the specific icon I'm talking about: http://www.fosslinux.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/Dash-to-Panel-enabled-desktop-on-Ubuntu-17.10.jpg

At first, my change was successful, however, later on, that area became blank, and although there is a gap between where that icon should be and the "show the desktop" icon and file manager, there is no icon there anymore.

**What I have done so far to fix the issue:**

- I have edited my LightDM GTK+ Greeter settings, both the theme and icon settings in there, but to no avail.
- I have navigated to `/usr/share/icons`, and edited the Adwaita and windows-10-master icons under their respective `/scalable/actions/view-app-grid-symbolic.svg` and `view-grid-symbolic.svg` icons with the appropriate .svg file icon I want to no available.

I am currently using the windows-10-master Icons theme (for icons generally) alongside the Adwaita-dark theme as well.

- I also tried editing the gnome-applications-panel.desktop file with the appropriate path (see below):

```
[Desktop Entry]  
Name=Applications  
Comment=Control various application permissions and settings  
Exec=gnome-control-center applications  
Icon=/usr/share/icons/windows-10-white--1.svg  
Terminal=false  
Type=Application  
NoDisplay=false  
StartupNotify=true  
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Settings;DesktopSettings;X-GNOME-Settings-Panel;X-GNOME-AccountSettings;  
OnlyShowIn=GNOME;Unity;   
Keywords=application;flatpak;permission;setting;  
X-GNOME-ControlCenter-HasSidebar=true  
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=gnome-control-center-2.0
```

So I'm kind of at my wits' end here. Not sure what more to do.

Comment: PS: I also tried editing the cinnamon-panel-launcher.svg file and replacing it with the appropriate one. That also did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay... welp... I definitely feel dumb now. The one obvious option I hadn't tried, was right clicking where that icon needed to go on the panel -> clicking configure -> then selecting an icon. The original directory and filename that it was pointing to had somehow been removed/deleted. I was able to put the proper one there.

Yup... pretty silly of me >_>

Comment: If you solved your answer please mark it as valid to close the case.

Comment: It says I can only accept my answer in "20 more hours". I will make sure to do this once the system allows me to.